# Selection of subsets

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, permutations

This is an supplementary exercise from Miklos Bona: *A walk through combinatorics*.

We want to select as many subsets of $[n]=\{1,2,3,..,n\}$ without selecting two subsets such that neither one of them contains the other.

At least we can select $\frac{2^n}{n}$ subsets was an option being considered. Can anyone give mathematical proof from this in general?

And is there any possibility that this answer can be improved?

Comment: If its $3$ then answer isnt integer i think its different

Comment: Could you include the exact wording of the question?

Answer (score 1):

We seek a maximal antichain in the discrete-cube poset. The limiting number is $\binom{n}{n/2}$.

Indeed, we can attain this by selecting all subsets which are of size exactly $n/2$. It can't be beaten: this result is known as Sperner's lemma, and it can be done by finding $\binom{n}{n/2}$ distinct maximal-length chains (that is, sequences of sets $A_1 \subset A_2 \subset \dots$). Each antichain can intersect a chain at most once, so that means an antichain must be of size at most $\binom{n}{n/2}$.

How do we do that? We use Hall's marriage theorem to find a matching from $\{ \text{subsets of size $i$} \}$ to $\{ \text{subsets of size $i+1$}\}$, for $i < \frac{n}{2}$, and use the symmetric matching for $i \geq \frac{n}{2}$. Then we can glue together the matchings to get a set of chains.

Comment: but what about the number $\frac{2^n}{n}$

Comment: @mea43 What do you mean?

Comment: I was trying to prove that if i take less than $\frac{2^n}{n}$ elements, this will violate condition that it will contain two subsets such that one contains the other. Can Pigeonhole principle be used in this regard?

Comment: No. Let $n=8$ and take all sets of size $4$. There are $70$ of these, and $2^8/8 = 32$ which is substantially less.